# htaccess rewrite if/else scenario?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

shortly: I want htaccess to decide, which of two css files to rewrite, depending on which one exists.

in detail: I want to include my css (later js, fonts, etc.) in the format vendor/project/style.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/project/style.css">
```

lets say that every project can be installed via composer, so it lands in the vendors folder. so the rewrite would easily be:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/(.*)\.css$ vendor/$1/$2/$3.css [L]
```

BUT: you could also clone every project directly to be the root project, so it does NOT land in the vendors folder. the rewrite then should look like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/(.*)\.css$ $3.css [L]
```

my question is now: how may i tell apache to check which file actually exists? I tried something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/(.*)\.css$     
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/vendor/%1/%2/%3\.css -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/(.*)\.css$ vendor/$1/$2/$3.css [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/(.*)\.css$     
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%3\.css -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/(.*)\.css$ $3.css [L]
```

but with no success at all.

Comment: because if I give rewrite to both, one will always fail.

Comment: without the recommended condition from @mike-rockett, I would try to rewrite to one file, that does not exist. because the file is either in vendors or in the local root. so, if I rewrite to vendor/project/style.css and this file does not exist, it will fail to load, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Check to see if file exists in `vendor`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.+)\.css$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/vendor/%1/%2/%3.css -f
RewriteRule ^ vendor/%1/%2/%3.css [L]

# Check to see if file exists in directory root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.+)\.css$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%3.css -f
RewriteRule ^ %3.css [L]
```

You can check against `REQUEST_URI`, and no need to check again in the rules (note the `%` in the rewrite destination). Also, have changed your matching groups to use `\w+` instead - this is shorthand for what you had before, with the exception that `*` has been replaced with `+` as the former would check for empty strings, too.

This has been tested on my local server, and works as expected.

Comment: the second one works perfectly, the first one ends up in an [INTERNAL REDIRECT]. not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Both were working fine for me. What URI are you testing with? For reference, I tested with `/test/test1/testing.css`, and then tested with a PHP file that outputs the value of `__FILE__` to make sure the correct file is being called.

Comment: I testes for root with: /scipper/haushalt/style_1.0.css - works
and for vendor with: /traiwi/traiwicore/style.css - does not work. 
apache resolves the absolute path perfectly correct to /var/www/haushalt/vendor/traiwi/traiwicore/style.css but does not rewrite to..

Comment: Anything else in your `.htaccess` file? There must be some sort of conflict going on, because those URIs work for me when both files are present.

Comment: the whole file looks like:<br/>

`RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.+)\.css$  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/vendor/%1/%2/%3.css -f  
RewriteRule ^ vendor/%1/%2/%3.css [L]  
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.+)\.css$  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%3.css -f  
RewriteRule ^ %3.css [L]  
  
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ client/uploads/$1 [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.ico$ $1.ico [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ client/main.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Strange, it is working for me. May be something to do with the `Options` Directive. Mine is set to `Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks`.

Comment: sadly this does not change anything :/

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know what's causing the problem. It *may* be the fact that you have set a `RewriteBase`, but I doubt it.